# Anyway to display speaker output volumes on an LCD display?

Tags: audio, lcd, speakers, spdif, surround-sound

I use a 6.1 system at home, outputting from my HTPC via optical (SPDIF).

I also have an antec fusion case, and I wanted to know if there was a way to display the speakers EQ levels on the LCD display?

I know that when you use AC3 filter, you can see a speaker output, which is exactly the kind of thing I'd like to see on my LCD display - I imagine you would have to use something like LCD smartie to achieve this?

[image: speakeroutput]

Answer (score 2):

It's fairly old software now, but I've done something similar with [LCDC](http://www.lcdc.cc/) and a [Matrix Orbital USB display](http://www.matrixorbital.com/-c-1_2.html) before, I think the [LCD Studio](http://www.lcdstudio.com/site20/home.php) software lets you do something similar.

You can see pictures on similar setups of [HTPCs on MO's forums](http://www.lcdforums.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=698).

Comment: +1 for suggesting LCDC, even if it doesn't work for this LCD (it very well might). It kicks butt for character LCDs.

Comment: Thanks for the LCDC link, however the 2nd link you provided appears to be dead...

I'll check out LCDC and report back!